# AddressSanitizer error while accessing value of a memory address though printf()

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, address-sanitizer

I have attended an algorithm competition where I have given a method to write an algorithm for a problem which is for language in C coding. The method was something like below:

```
int algorithm(char** grid, int gridSize, int* gridColSize)
{...}
```

If I give an input to server a value for a grid:

> []

Then I have received "AddressSanitizer ERROR heap-buffer-overflow"

when I printf() the value gridColSize like below:

```
printf("[%d]", gridColSize);
```

It prints:

> [16]

If I print like below then the memory error shows at the editor's terminal

```
printf("[%d]", *gridColSize);
```

As I can't access the hidden code at server. How can I possibly check and deal with the input value "[]" for **grid** parameter.

For the following input where row and column values are valid it does not appears such case. if row is zero column may have valid value >= 1, so how can I check the gridColSize address is a valid memory and I can skip that input for returning a valid output?

I have seen many topics in internet about why address sanitizer issues happens but I have know how can I deal with this situation when I can't access main code.

Would someone help me out to solve it brilliantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I check the gridColSize address is a valid memory and I can skip that input for returning a valid output?

You can't check if memory pointed by given non-NULL pointer can or can not be accessed.

Given API of `algorithm` function you can:

1. check if `grid` is `NULL`.
2. check if `gridSize` is 0.
3. check if `gridColSize` is `NULL`.

Given that you checked 3 (`gridColSize` was `16`) try checking `gridSize`.

Comment: Thank you. That is wise.

Answer (score 0):

this statement:

```
printf("[%d]", *gridColSize);
```

is requesting printing the value at address (per your question) 16.

Most likely address 16 is NOT a valid address for your program to use.